# XML to Object Conversion for Field Type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

I need to make Object as per my xml, this object will be used as input for a webservice in c#.

If i have this xml,

```
<v1:Field type="Note">
   <v1:name>Buyer’s Name should be as per Passport / Trade License. For existing Emaar property owners, please provide details as per existing profile.</v1:name>
   <v1:category>MESSAGE</v1:category>
   <v1:mandatory>N</v1:mandatory>
   <v1:alias>DESCLAIMER_FYI</v1:alias>
   <v1:value>Buyer’s Name should be as per Passport / Trade License. For existing Emaar property owners, please provide details as per existing profile.</v1:value>
</v1:Field>
```

I can make class based on it,
for example

```
public class Field
{
    public string name{ set; get; }
    public string category { set; get; }
    public string mandatory { set; get; }
    public string alias { set; get; }
    public string value { set; get; }
}
```

Which attribute will be used to take this value 
`<`v1:Field **type="Note"**`>`?

if i make type as public property, it will come as tag in xml like name, category are coming but i want to make it with Field tag, which is called attribute. What can i use in C# which will act as an attribute coming with Field tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SomeIntInfo
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq.  I test code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("v1");

            var results = root.Descendants(ns + "Field").Select(x => new Field() {
                type = (string)x.Attribute("type"),
                name = (string)x.Element(ns + "name"),
                category = (string)x.Element(ns + "category"),
                mandatory = (string)x.Element(ns + "mandatory"),
                alias = (string)x.Element(ns + "alias"),
                value = (string)x.Element(ns + "value"),
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    public class Field
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { set; get; }
        public string category { set; get; }
        public string mandatory { set; get; }
        public string alias { set; get; }
        public string value { set; get; }
    }
}
```